# Can't start jackd

Tags: audio, alsa

I realize there are many threads about not being able to start jackd, but none of the solutions provided have been able to cure my issue.

```
pi@raspberrypi / $ jackd -v -d alsa
jackdmp 1.9.9
Copyright 2001-2005 Paul Davis and others.
Copyright 2004-2012 Grame.
jackdmp comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; see the file COPYING for details
JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
Cannot lock down 82278944 byte memory area (Cannot allocate memory)
Jack: JackPosixThread::StartImp : create non RT thread
Jack: JackPosixThread::ThreadHandler : start
Jack: JackDriver::Open capture_driver_name = hw:0
Jack: JackDriver::Open playback_driver_name = hw:0
Jack: Check protocol client = 8 server = 8
Jack: JackEngine::ClientInternalOpen: name = system
Jack: JackEngine::AllocateRefNum ref = 0
Jack: JackPosixSemaphore::Allocate name = jack_sem.1000_default_system val = 0
Jack: JackEngine::NotifyAddClient: name = system
Jack: JackGraphManager::SetBufferSize size = 1024
Jack: JackConnectionManager::DirectConnect first: ref1 = 0 ref2 = 0
Jack: JackGraphManager::ConnectRefNum cur_index = 0 ref1 = 0 ref2 = 0
Jack: JackDriver::SetupDriverSync driver sem in flush mode
control device hw:0
control device hw:0
Failed to connect to session bus for device reservation Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11

Failed to acquire device name : Audio0 error : Invalid argument
Audio device hw:0 cannot be acquired...
Jack: ~JackDriver
Cannot initialize driver
Jack: no message buffer overruns
Jack: JackPosixThread::Stop
Jack: JackPosixThread::ThreadHandler : exit
JackServer::Open failed with -1
Jack: Succeeded in unlocking 82278944 byte memory area
Jack: JackShmMem::delete size = 0 index = 0
Jack: ~JackDriver
Jack: Succeeded in unlocking 1040 byte memory area
Jack: JackShmMem::delete size = 0 index = 1
Jack: Cleaning up shared memory
Jack: Cleaning up files
Jack: Unregistering server `default'
Failed to open server
```

That's the output after a fresh reboot, running as root. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does `aplay -D hw:0 something.wav` work?

Comment: It does. Strangely `aplay something.wav` (without declaring the device) has to be run with sudo though.

Comment: Show the output of `jackd -v -d alsa`.

Comment: @CL. replaced question with verbose log

Comment: Execute `export DISPLAY=:0` before your command.

Comment: @vaha This is the output after `export DISPLAY=:0` - https://gist.github.com/rob-gordon/96e9a0f273b1bf0320f2439ed46e203a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message **Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11** in the first verbose log means that your DISPLAY variable is not set properly.

Before your command, to set it properly just execute:

```
# export DISPLAY=:0
```

The message **Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed** in the second vebose log means that `jackd` cannot init an `X client`. I guess you are working on a raspi which does not have a running `X server`.

**If X Window System is installed on your raspi**, just start `X Server` before your command:

```
# startx
```

**If you don't want X Window System installed on your raspi:**

(While being unsure) you can try the followings:

1. If you are on a ssh terminal (not the console), start your ssh with **-X** or **-Y** argument (i.e. `ssh -X root@your_raspi_ip`) and do not forget to execute `export ...` command mentioned above before your command. **It is required that X server is running on your local.**
2. If you are on the console, try to start `jackd` without `X client` as suggested at [Start JACK without X](https://linuxmusicians.com/viewtopic.php?t=12821#p55309). You may need to install `jackdbus` in addition.

   Before your command, execute:

   `export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/dbus/system_bus_socket`

Comment: Method 1, returns a very slightly different error. https://gist.github.com/rob-gordon/94417801ffcf811b22a8e6ce04b119ab - I don't think X is running despite the ssh flag. I was only able to make it run after running `startx` ultimately :\ I'm marking this correct, however, because I think it will help people in the future.

Comment: Haha, I assumed you are using a Linux machine, but I see it is a Mac. I don't know if Macs have a running `X server` on them.  `ssh -X` or  `ssh -Y` simply provides `X client of raspi` to connect to `X server` of your Linux machine, **it does not start `X server` on the raspi**.